# How to authenticate Instagram app in deliverable code?

Tags: instagram-api

I'm building PHP tools on a colleague's website to show their Instagram media on their website. I understand that the current procedure is to [authenticate the application](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) and use an `access_token` to fetch media.

> Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL
>   Step Two: Receive the redirect from Instagram
>   Step Three: Request the access_token

The workflow seems to be:

1. Direct the user to the authentication URL, passing the `client_id`.
2. The user authenticates and is returned to the callback URL.
3. My page receives the returned `code`.
4. Send the `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `code` to receive an `access_token`.
5. Use the `access_token` to fetch media from the API.

The problem is that I will be delivering this code to my colleague and I do not want to hardcode my `client_secret`. So, I'm assuming I can't use my own developer account. Does my colleague need to create their own developer account, register an app, and get their own `client_id` and `client_secret`?

Would this be the correct workflow for my situation?

1. Instruct my colleague to create a developer account, register an app, and get a `client_id` and `client_secret`.
2. Prompt them to enter their `client_id` into a form on their site.
3. Submit the form to the Instagram Authentication URL and receive the returned `code`.
4. Prompt them to enter enter their `client_id` *again* with their `client_secret` into a form.
5. Send the `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `code` and retrieve the `access_token` (using CURL).
6. Store the `access_token` in the database for later use.

Comment: Please do the research properly. The flow is documented widely whenever oauth is in the play

Comment: I've done research, but I don't understand how to develop the application without giving away my own `client_secret` when I deliver my code. Documentation does not seem to address this situation. Do you have any suggestions of where to look?

Comment: No. The fact you searched does not mean you do the proper research as you seem confused what secret client ID and tokens are for and which one belong to user and which to your app. You also seem confused how your user should authenticate using instagram. As I said oauth related tutorials should be all you need to understand to have your doubts answered.

Comment: I believe the client_id and client_secret belong to my app and not the user. [Like this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/oauth2.0/images/OAuth_diagram.jpg). But when I deliver the code, my client_secret will be visible in the code. I don't want that. So I'm wondering if the user needs to register their own app. A little advice would be helpful, rather than just telling me I'm confused.

Comment: Shortly: if you want to distribute just code for others to grab, deploy and run then their need to provide all this incl. **their** id and secret (make it part of your app config, and they have to register dev accounts to obtain that - no other way exists). If you want to run that site by yourself then these should be yours. User authentication is the same in both cases

Comment: Ok, thank you. It seems they will need their own developer account and will need to enter their client_id and client_secret as part of the app config. Much appreciated!

Comment: Yes. They need own secret and client id. How to get that depends on the site you want to integrate with as this is irrelevant. You need to simply follow what the 3rd party site requires you to follow to get these.